# sql how to use case?

Tags: sql, case

Hello  i have 2 tables 1 with btwvalues and 1 with orders

I am trying to select the final rate (

```
    if extrahours =1 then finalhourscost = extrahoursrate 
    else finalhourcost = hoursrate)
```

i have made an example

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd8d9/17

So what i want is create a row finalhourscost depending on both tables. finalhourcost is not an existing row.

What have i done wrong , as you see it returns 1 instead of 40

Comment: thx the example was made with if and else wich i didn't knew that werked in sql

Comment: My bad, need more coffee this morning. The example and the fiddle both don't work... The answer below does though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT extrahours, 
       extrahourrate,
       hourrate,
       CASE extrahours WHEN 0 THEN extrahourrate ELSE hourrate END AS finalrate
FROM bill JOIN cost ON bill.costid = cost.id
```